# dialog box not shown in an activity group

Tags: android, dialog, radio-button

I have a Tabactivity
Where in i have 4 tabs. one of the tab has many child activities displayed via ActivityGroup..i have radio buttons inside one of the child activity..on click of any of the radio button i need to display a dialog box...m not able to display the dialog box.....i am getting an error like:

```
android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.app.LocalActivityManager$LocalActivityRecord@412369a0 is not valid; is your activity running?
```

an my code is here:

```
public class BabyProducts extends ActivityGroup {

Button back,home;

RadioGroup rg_babybath,
Context context=this;
String babybath;

RadioButton rb_babybath;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.babyproducts);

    rg_babybath=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radioGroup_babybath);

    back=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_back);
    home=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_home);
    back.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent activity2=new Intent(v.getContext(),Inventory.class);
            replaceContentView("activity2", activity2);

        }
    });

    home.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent activity2=new Intent(v.getContext(),AuditActivity.class);
            replaceContentView("activity2", activity2);

        }
    });

    rg_babybath.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            rb_babybath=(RadioButton)findViewById(checkedId);
            babybath=rb_babybath.getText().toString();
            option(babybath);


}

});
}

public void option(String bbath)
{
    if(bbath.equals("Yes")){
        final Dialog dialog=new Dialog(BabyProducts.this);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.popup_stock);
        dialog.setTitle("Choose");
        Button save=(Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.save);
        Button submit=(Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.submit);


        save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                dialog.dismiss();
            }

        });

        submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        dialog.show();

    }

    if(bbath.equals("No")){
        final Dialog dialog=new Dialog(BabyProducts.this);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.popup_reason);
        dialog.setTitle("Choose");
        Button save=(Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.save);
        Button submit=(Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.submit);


        save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                dialog.dismiss();
            }

        });

        submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        dialog.show();

    }


}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void replaceContentView(String id, Intent newIntent)
{
    View view=getLocalActivityManager().startActivity(id, newIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)).getDecorView();
    this.setContentView(view);
}


}
```

Comment: nope not working! still getiing the same error

Comment: @shivani please check the value of babybath in onCheckedChanged(i.e. when you are calling your method option) and instead of writing equals in if write equalIgnoreCase.

Comment: @ChiragJain will it work if i pu my whole code in oncreate method and not in options method???

Comment: I think you should just check values bBath because if you are getting something other than Yes or No then your dialog will not appear.

Comment: @ChiragJain it has the values YES or No only....no other values..i checked by showing toast message

Answer (score 0):

```
Activity activity = getActivty.getParent();

if (activity != null)
  Dialog dialog=new Dialog(activity);
```

Answer (score 0):

The likely issue might be the `v.getContext()` in your radio group onclick listener. Try any of these instead of it `getBaseContext()` or `getApplicationContext()` or try passing your `context` object.

Comment: why is it showing this error for dialog.show() when the problem is for application context??. i tried getBaseContext() and getApplicationcontext()... not working..

Comment: It seems the exception links with the context of your view since it is an activity group and you haven't used your `context` object in your code. Try changing the code by replacing every context of the view or activity to `context` object.

Answer (score 0):

just try to use :

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getParent());
```